# Compound Poisson process property

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Let $X_t=\sum_{i=1}^{N_t}J_i$ be a compound Poisson Process, where $J_i$ are independent and equidistributed.

I have to prove that for every $0<t_1<t_2 \leq t_3<t_4$ : $X_{t_4}-X_{t_3}$ is independent of $X_{t_3}-X_{t_2}$.

So if I demonstrate that, $$\mathbb{P}(X_{t_4}-X_{t_3}\leq s, X_{t_2}-X_{t_1}\leq t )= \mathbb{P}(X_{t_4}-X_{t_3} J_i\leq s)\mathbb{P}(X_{t_2}-X_{t_1} J_i\leq t)$$ it would be finished.

I have that:

$$\mathbb{P}(X_{t_4}-X_{t_3} J_i\leq s, X_{t_2}-X_{t_1}J_i \leq t )  = \mathbb{P}(\sum_{N_{t_3}+1}^{N_{t_4}} J_i\leq s, \sum_{N_{t_1}+1}^{N_{t_2}}J_i\leq t )$$
Since $N_t$ only takes integer values, the last expresion is the same as:
   $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(\sum_{N_{t_3}+1}^{N_{t_4}}J_i \leq s, \sum_{N_{t_1}+1}^{N_{t_2}}J_i\leq t )|N_{t_4}-N_{t_3}=n,N_{t_2}-N_{t_1}=m)\mathbb{P}(N_{t_4}-N_{t_3}=n,N_{t_2}-N_{t_1}=m)$$ and since $N_t$ is independent of $J_i$ we have that:

In this context, I don´t know how to follow to complete my proof: I know that I have to use that $N_t$ is independent of $J_i$, $N_{t_4}-N_{t_3}$ is independent of $N_{t_2}-N_{t_1}$ and that $J_i$ are independent and equidistributed.

Any suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: What is _your_ definition of a Poisson process, and of a _compound_ Poisson process? In many treatments of Poisson processes, the independent increments property is an axiom, and people then _prove_ that the process is Poisson distributed, that inter-arrival times are exponential, etc. For such people, there is nothing to prove: the independence you seek  to prove is an axiom. So, where are _you_ starting from when you say the process is a (compound) Poisson process?

Comment: Sure, my definition of the Poisson Process is the next: $\displaystyle N_{t}=\sum_{n=0}^{ \infty}n {1}_{\lbrace{T_{n}{\leq}t<T_{n+1}}\rbrace}$ 
where $\tau_{n}$ are independent and exponential distributed

Comment: My biggest problem, is that I do not how to argue that:$$\mathbb{P}(\sum^{N_{t_4}-N_{t_3}}_{i=1}J_i  \leq n)=\mathbb{P}(\sum^{N_{t_4}}_{i=N_{t_3}+1}J_i  \leq n)$$

Comment: The basic problem is that your definition of a Poisson process is incorrect: If $\lbrace T_n\rbrace$ is a collection of independent (exponential) random variables, then there is no guarantee that $T_{n+1}$ is larger than $T_n$. Thus, the function ${\mathbf 1}_{\lbrace{T_{n}{\leq}t<T_{n+1}}\rbrace}$ might have value $0$ for all $t$ and none of the $N_t$ can take on value $n$. What you need are the _order statistics_ $\lbrace T_{(n)}\rbrace$ of $\lbrace T_n\rbrace$ in your  ${\mathbf 1}_{\lbrace{T_{n}{\leq}t<T_{n+1}}\rbrace}$, and the order statistics are _not_ independent random variables.

Comment: No, it is correct. $T_n$ are not exponential, but $\tau_n=T_n-T_{n-1}$. But the definiyion in this case is irrelevant, since I can use all the preoperties of the Poisson Process I want...

Comment: @DilipSarwate Do you know how to demostrate that $\mathbb{P}(\sum^{N_{t_4}-N_{t_3}}_{i=1}J_i  \leq n)=\mathbb{P}(\sum^{N_{t_4}}_{i=N_{t_3}+1}J_i  \leq n)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I follow the same path as you:

\begin{eqnarray*}
&& P\left(X_{t_3}-X_{t_2}\leq s \;\bigcap\; X_{t_4}-X_{t_3}\leq t\right) \\
&&\qquad = P\left(\sum_{i=N_{t_2}+1}^{N_{t_3}} J_i\leq s \;\bigcap\; \sum_{i=N_{t_3}+1}^{N_{t_4}} J_i\leq t\right) \\
&& \\
&&\qquad = P\left(\sum_{i=1}^{N_{t_3}-N_{t_2}} J_i\leq s \;\bigcap\; \sum_{i=N_{t_3}-N_{t_2}+1}^{N_{t_4}-N_{t_2}} J_i\leq t\right) \\
&&\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\text{re-index the $J_i$ from $1$ (OK since $J_i$ are i.i.d.)} \\
&& \\
&&\qquad = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} P\left(\sum_{i=1}^{N_{t_3} - N_{t_2}} J_i\leq s \;\bigcap\; \sum_{i=N_{t_3} - N_{t_2}+1}^{N_{t_4} - N_{t_2}} J_i\leq t \; \bigg| \; N_{t_3} - N_{t_2}=n\cap N_{t_4} - N_{t_3}=m\right) \\
&&\qquad\qquad \qquad \times P\left(N_{t_3} - N_{t_2}=n\right)P\left(N_{t_4} - N_{t_3}=m\right) \\
&&\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\text{condition on the values of $N(t)$} \\
&& \\
&&\qquad = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} P\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} J_i\leq s \;\bigcap\; \sum_{i=n+1}^{n+m} J_i\leq t \right) P\left(N_{t_3} - N_{t_2}=n\right)P\left(N_{t_4} - N_{t_3}=m\right) \\
&&\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\text{since $J_i$ and $N(t)$ are independent} \\
&& \\
&&\qquad = \left[ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} J_i\leq s \right) P\left(N_{t_3} - N_{t_2}=n\right) \right] \left[ \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} P\left(\sum_{i=1}^{m} J_i\leq t \right)P\left(N_{t_4} - N_{t_3}=m\right)\right] \\
&&\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\text{since the $J_i$ are independent of each other} \\
&& \\
&&\qquad = P\left(\sum_{i=N_{t_2}+1}^{N_{t_3}} J_i\leq s \right) P\left(\sum_{i=N_{t_3}+1}^{N_{t_4}} J_i\leq t \right) \\
&&\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\text{undo the conditioning on the values of $N(t)$} \\
&& \\
&&\qquad = P\left(X_{t_3}-X_{t_2}\leq s\right) P\left(X_{t_4}-X_{t_3}\leq t\right). \\
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: My answer would be okay, @Mick A? Thanks a lot for your time. I have only a doubt: Why, if $J_i$ are i.i.d then : $$\mathbb{P}(\sum^{N_{t_4}-N_{t_3}}_{i=1}J_i  \leq n)=\mathbb{P}(\sum^{N_{t_4}}_{i=N_{t_3}+1}J_i  \leq n)$$

Comment: @Edin_91 If $J_i$ are i.i.d. then as long as you are summing the same number of them, then it's valid. In simple cases: $P(J_1\leq n)=P(J_2\leq n),\;P(J_1+J_2\leq n)=P(J_3+J_4\leq n),\;$ etc.

Comment: I Understand that $P(J_1\leq n)=P(J_2\leq n)$, but how can I prove that this impiles that P(J_1+J_2\leq n)=P(J_3+J_4\leq n)?

Comment: @Edin_91 If the $J_i$ are i.i.d. then it's true not just for sums but for any measurable function $g(x_1,\ldots,x_k)$ that $P(g(J_1,\ldots,J_k) \leq n)=P(g(J_{k+1},\ldots,J_{2k}) \leq n)$. This is really what it means for random variables to be i.i.d.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot! So according to my  case (for any $t_1<t_2 \leq t_3 <t_4$) it would be:
\begin{eqnarray*}
&& P\left(X_{t_4}-X_{t_3}\leq s \;\bigcap\; X_{t_2}-X_{t_1}\leq t\right) \\
&&\qquad = P\left(\sum_{i=N_{t_3}+1}^{N_{t_4}} J_i\leq s \;\bigcap\; \sum_{i=N_{t_1}+1}^{N_{t_2}} J_i\leq t\right) \\
&& \\
&&\qquad = P\left(\sum_{i=1}^{N_{t_4}-N_{t_3}} J_i\leq s \;\bigcap\; \sum_{i=1}^{N_{t_2}-N_{t_1}} J_i\leq t\right) \\
&&\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\text{re-index the $J_i$ from $1$ (OK since $J_i$ are i.i.d.)} \\
&& \\
&&\qquad = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} P\left(\sum_{i=1}^{N_{t_4} - N_{t_3}} J_i\leq s \;\bigcap\; \sum_{i=1}^{N_{t_2} - N_{t_1}} J_i\leq t \; \bigg| \; N_{t_4} - N_{t_3}=n\cap N_{t_2} - N_{t_1}=m\right) \\
&&\qquad\qquad \qquad \times P\left(N_{t_4} - N_{t_3}=n,N_{t_2} - N_{t_1}=m\right) \\
&&\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\text{condition on the values of $N(t)$} \\
&&\qquad = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} P\left(\sum_{i=1}^{N_{t_4} - N_{t_3}} J_i\leq s \;\bigcap\; \sum_{i=1}^{N_{t_2} - N_{t_1}} J_i\leq t \; \bigg| \; N_{t_4} - N_{t_3}=n\cap N_{t_2} - N_{t_1}=m\right) \\
&&\qquad\qquad \qquad \times P\left(N_{t_3} - N_{t_2}=n\right) P\left(N_{t_4} - N_{t_3}=m\right) \\
&&\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\text{$N(t)$ has independent increments} \\
&& \\
&&\qquad = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} P\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} J_i\leq s \;\bigcap\; \sum_{i=1}^{m} J_i\leq t \right) P\left(N_{t_4} - N_{t_3}=n\right)P\left(N_{t_2} - N_{t_1}=m\right) \\
&&\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\text{since $J_i$ and $N(t)$ are independent} \\
&& \\
&&\qquad = \left[ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} J_i\leq s \right) P\left(N_{t_4} - N_{t_3}=n\right) \right] \left[ \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} P\left(\sum_{i=1}^{m} J_i\leq t \right)P\left(N_{t_2} - N_{t_1}=m\right)\right] \\
&&\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\text{since the $J_i$ are independent of each other} \\
&& \\
&&\qquad = P\left(\sum_{i=N_{t_3}+1}^{N_{t_4}} J_i\leq s \right) P\left(\sum_{i=N_{t_1}+1}^{N_{t_2}} J_i\leq t \right) \\
&&\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\text{undo the conditioning on the values of $N(t)$} \\
&& \\
&&\qquad = P\left(X_{t_4}-X_{t_3}\leq s\right) P\left(X_{t_2}-X_{t_1}\leq t\right). \\
\end{eqnarray*}